# Installing 64 bit app using 64bit MS access on a computer that contains Win 7/Vista 64 bit and MS office 32 bit installed

Tags: .net, windows-7, 64-bit, ms-access-2010

We have an old software application originally developed for 32 bit OS but later ported 64 bit versions of Windows. The application uses MS-Access as a database and the 64bit version of the software used the 64bit MS-Access. The problem we are facing is with the installation of this application on Windows 7/Vista OS which has MS Office 32 bit intalled on it. The problem is as follows:

When the applicaiton is installed on the above environment the installer says that the user needs to uninstall the 32bit version of MS-Office while as a user I expect that the application should not bother about the version of MS Office already installed on the system?.

As a work around to this I have found that if we uninstall the 32 bit MS office, then install my application and finally re-install the 32bit MS office then there is no problem

What component do I need to include in my installer package or what changes do I need to make in my code so that the problem does not exists and the user can install my 64bit application without uninstalling his 32bit MS Office?

Comment: We are using Ace Database Engine for 64 bit support in our application and to me it appears that it is the Ace Database Engine that ask to uninstall 32 bit MS Office. Is there any workaround that we can do so that our user does not need to uninstall his 32bit MS Office

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and this seems to solve it (without having to uninstall the 32bit MS office):

1. Install the [64 bit access driver](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)
2. Run a command prompt **as administrator**
3. run the file downloaded in 1 in quite mode (not sure if this is strictly necessary, but it worked):

   AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /q